# How to add django Group field to a Customer User Register

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I used this Code in serializer.py:

```
    group = Group.objects.get()
    group.user_set.add(self.object)
```

It works fine when the Group Field has just one item: it is added in the DB with no problem.
But when I add more than one item in the Group List Field, I am getting an error:

```
get() returned more than one Group -- it returned 2!
```

What would you recommend I do to fix this?

[Image: For one item, it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdEAK.png)

[Image: With more than one item, I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dhLj.png)

This is my full code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    def validate(self, data):
        if not data.get('password') or not data.get('confirm_password'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter a password and ""confirm it.")
        if data.get('password') != data.get('confirm_password'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Those passwords don't match.")
        return data
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
            email=validated_data['email']
    )
        group = Group.objects.get()
        group.user_set.add(self.object)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'username',
            'password',
            'confirm_password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'groups',
        )
```

Comment: What "Group" are you trying to add the user to? It is very difficult to help without that detail. Is there more than one group you are trying to add the user to?

Comment: if I have two groups .. For example Admin and Manager I want to select both in the group list field to be added in the user which I will register .. I want select both as well as I press post to register new user the two groups will add to this user .. Any way I am trying to make API URL for the admin site for GUI app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group,User

user_list = User.objects.filter(some_filtering)
group = Group.objects.get(id=group_id)
group.user_set.add(*user_list)
```

Here I assumes that you have some kind of logic to get multiple user objects, which I stored to `user_list` variable. It can be passed to `add()` as `argument list`.

**Note:** `user_list` can be either `list of user instances` or `list of user-ids`